# GroupLayout - How to make layout maintain the same arrangement after resize

Tags: java, swing, grouplayout

I have set the constraints so that my components are resized together with the window. My problem is that the order is then destroyed because their positions get off. Is there an equivalent to GridBagConstraints.anchor in GroupLayout?

Before resize : 
[image]

After resize : 
[image]

[EDIT]
Here is my code : 
[Edit # 2]
Here is my code that is runnable :

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ConnectUI extends JPanel {
    private static JTextField textField;
    private static JTable table;

    public static JButton submit;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();        
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new ConnectUI());
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public ConnectUI() {

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblAvailable = new JLabel("Available : ");
        lblAvailable.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username : ");
        lblUsername.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        submit = new JButton("Submit");

        JLabel lblClient = new JLabel("CLIENT");
        lblClient.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        JLabel lblWarning = new JLabel("Username must not exceed 15 characters and a server must be selected");
        lblWarning.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(lblUsername, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(lblAvailable, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .addGap(452))))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(196)
                            .addComponent(lblClient, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 132, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGap(134)))
                    .addGap(38))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(200)
                    .addComponent(submit, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 102, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(198))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(68)
                    .addComponent(lblWarning, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 357, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(75))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(120)
                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 150, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(230))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblClient, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(31)
                            .addComponent(lblUsername, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(lblAvailable, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 4, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 210, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(37)
                    .addComponent(lblWarning, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(submit, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(69))
        );

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "Room", "Host", "IP"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] columnEditables = new boolean[] {
                false, false, false
            };
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return columnEditables[column];
            }
        });
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        setLayout(groupLayout);

    }

}
```

Comment: Add the minimal amount of code which demonstrates this problem and that we can run ourselves.

Comment: Your code does not compile, I wrote "*that we can run ourselves*", which means that you need to remove all unnecessary lines, copy-paste it into a blank file in your editor and make sure it runs by itself. Also, make sure all variables are defined

Comment: "*Here is my code that is runnable*" Are you sure? Did you copy-paste it into an empty file in a separate project? Where did you define `Main`? What about this line `addActionListener(new Action())`?

Comment: I re-editted it so that it does not require the Main class anymore. It should compile fine on it's own now.

Comment: Excellent! For future reference, this is the type of code you're expected to provide in your questions. Now I can see the problem, as you said, that the username `textField` and `submit` button resize horizontally. What result do you want to get when resizing?

Comment: Also, `GroupLayout` is an overkill for this GUI. I see that you used a GUI builder and I suggest you learn to code GUIs yourself instead. Do you want to solve this problem with maintaining `GroupLayout` or would you consider a simpler, more intuitive approach?

Comment: I have moderate knowledge on coding GUIs via the GridBagLayout but I couldn't get the layout that I wanted. That's why I decided to try to use a GUI builder. I would appreciate it if there was a simpler approach.

Comment: And what about my previous question?

Comment: Oh. I wanted it to retain the same relative position after resizing. Basically, it would look exactly the same, just with larger components.

Comment: Can be done, but it makes little sense to resize buttons (look at your expanded submit button) and also text labels since the font size usually remains constant. For a text field, resizing it vertically is meaningless because it's a 1-line component. Subjectively, I would say that you only need to resize the table. What do you think?